# iOS11: UIBarButtonItem with custom view not resizing on rotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I have this:

[image]

And the icons get all out of wack when I rotate (they don't resize and reposition like they did in <11):

[image]

This is how I'm implementing the code. I set my `UINavigationBars` with `UIBarButtonItem` with custom image as follows:

```
- (void) loadNavigationBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)navigationBarButton withSpacerWidth:(CGFloat)spacerWidth barButtonDirection:(CGFloat)barButtonDirection
{
        NSArray* items = @[navigationBarButton];

        if (barButtonDirection == 0)
        {
            [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:items animated:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:items animated:NO];
        }
}
```

And this is how I initialize one of the `UIBarButtonItems`:

```
- (void) loadDefaultRightButton
{
    ButtonView *rightButtonView = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.71090047393365, 44) image:[[[NextButtonIcon alloc] initWithHighlight:NO] imageForSize:CGSizeMake(60.71090047393365, 44)] highlightFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.71090047393365, 44) highlightImage:[[[NextButtonIcon alloc] initWithHighlight:YES] imageForSize:CGSizeMake(60.71090047393365, 44)] highlightOnTop:YES buttonViewType:ButtonViewTypeNext roundedCorners:NO enableDisabledView: NO  doubleTap:NO singleTapGestureRecognizer:nil];
    rightButtonView.delegate = self;
    [rightButtonView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: 60.71090047393365].active = YES;
    [rightButtonView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: 44].active = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButtonView];
    [self loadNavigationBarButton:rightButton withSpacerWidth:21 barButtonDirection:1];
}
```

For some reason now, when I rotate to landscape, but `UIBarButtonItems` don't resize themselves like they used to. They stay big and overflow off the screen. Does anyone know why this is happening? My `UIViewControllers` take up the full screen fwiw.

UPDATE: Added images and other clarifying comments.